# stopping a goroutine from outside the go routine

Tags: go, memory-leaks, goroutine

I have a go routine here that needs to be stopped from the outer go routine when the context expires. However, the go routine doesn't stop when the context expires and keeps on going even though the go routine controlling it stops.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctxParent := context.Background()

    ch := make(chan bool)

    d := 5 * time.Second

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctxParent, d)
    defer cancel()
    go doSomething(ctx, ch)

    // go func() {
    select {

    // done
    case _ = <-ch:
        fmt.Println("goroutine finished")
    }

    fmt.Println("waiting 11 seconds on main thread, ending all go routines")

    time.Sleep(11 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println(">>>> END")
}

func doSomething(ctx context.Context, ch chan<- bool) {

    // how to kill this go routine if context expires??
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        fmt.Println("LOTS OF WORK TIME..")
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // LOTS OF WORK
            fmt.Println(i)
        }

    }(ctx)

    select {
    case _ = <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("*** Go routine timed out in 5 seconds!!! ****")
        ch <- true
        return

    }
}
```

this will print (https://play.golang.org/p/L8u51odiHxS)

```
LOTS OF WORK TIME..
0
1
2
3
4
*** Go routine timed out in 5 seconds!!! ****
goroutine finished
waiting 11 seconds on main thread, ending all go routines
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
>>>> END
```

it should not be printing 5,6,7,8... etc.. Is there a way to kill this inner go routine?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the context in the goroutine that's printing.

Comment: Go routines are not hierarchical.  Control and synchronization needs to be explicit.  Your anonymous function takes a `context.Context` argument but does nothing with it

Comment: There is no ID—no *name*, in other words—for a goroutine, hence no way to murder it from outside, as a kill function would require an ID for the goroutine to be murdered. Go routines must therefore be convinced to commit suicide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check for context expiration/cancellation in the goroutine:

```
 go func(ctx context.Context) {
        fmt.Println("LOTS OF WORK TIME..")
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            select {
              case <-ctx.Done():
                  return
              default:
            }
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // LOTS OF WORK
            fmt.Println(i)
        }

    }(ctx)
```

Comment: might make sense to poll the `ctx.Done()` after each loop iteration as well.

Comment: @colm.anseo I thought I had it in the loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like Burak Serdar says, you have to check the status of the context within the goroutine, but not just at the start of the goroutine: you have to do it regularly within the goroutine.

```
go func(ctx context.Context) {
  for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
      return
    default:
      // do some work
    }
  }
}(ctx)
```

Generally speaking, a goroutine should not be killed from the outside; it has to check and realize by itself that it's time is up.